# JPA mapping - composite FK with date-range

Tags: java, sql, jpa, orm, mapping

I am trying to solve following problem:

I have one table of ***ORDERS*** that contains: **group of goods**, **type of goods** and **order date**...this refers to table with ***GOODS***, where **group**, **type** and **valid-from** is the PK + **valid-to** field.

I had a dream, that I can map goods to orders using JPA to save multiple SQL queries.

I believe I can basically use following aproach to map the composite relationship:

```
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "heilgruppe", referencedColumnName = "heilgruppe"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "code", referencedColumnName = "heilmittel_code")
    })
```

But I have troubles with the date attribute...because I obviously cannot just use "equals" to map one date field to another...I need to select such goods, where date of the order lies between valid-from and valid-to dates

But how to do it with JPA? Is it even possible to do it? Or am I forced to create new SQL query later in code to retrive required info?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use composite PK in GOODS, but a technical ID (maybe generated) and you will avoid that problem and use this PK in ORDERS.

Or use the all GOODS composite PK in ORDERS and add valid-from in ORDERS (but it not the best way).

Comment: The problem is I cannot alter neither the table of ORDERS nor GOODS...we are developing above a complex, live system, many years old...we need to use it as it is :( The issue of selecting correct data from GOODS is easy to solve using SQL, but I wanted to save extra query. But maybe it is not even possible under given circumstances.